# What is the use of fetchRegistry property in eureka server?

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka

If Eureka client doesn't register itself with the eureka server by setting eureka: client: registerWithEureka: false, why does fetchRegistry property also needs to be set as false?

Comment: https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-eureka-client-server-communication#fetch-registry

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`registerWithEureka` controls whether or not this client registers itself and therefore becomes **discoverable**. This alone does not imply that this client is going to fetch the information on other services' endpoints and therefore being able to connect to them.

`fetchRegistry` controls whether or not this client is going to try to connect to the Eureka server(s) in order to download the information on other services' endpoint. It can do so without registering itself.
Quoting the [documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-eureka-client-server-communication#fetch-registry):

> **Fetch Registry**
>
> Eureka clients fetches the registry information from the server and caches it locally. After that, the clients use that information to find other services.

Answer (score 6):

Eureka client need to register with eureka server to become discoverable.
Eureka server can act as client as well. So setting registerWith Eureka and fetchRegistry to false is mandatory

Only clients need to fetch registry to get the registered microservices for communication
EurekaServer need not register itself  and also need not fetch other registered Microservices

Comment: "*setting registerWith Eureka and fetchRegistry to false is mandatory*" - what if you want multiple Eureka servers to register with each other to create a network of nodes? If a eureka server registers with another server, and both fetch each others registry, do they not create a virtual cluster? Especially if you add Zuul, services from one node should failover to another node if they are grouped this way.

Answer (score 1):

Two properties, eureka.client.fetch-registry and eureka.client.register-with-eureka,
are properties that you might set on another microservice
to tell them how they should interact with Eureka. But  Eureka is also a
microservice, so these properties can be used with a Eureka server to tell it how it
should interact with other Eureka servers.

The default value for both of these properties is true, indicating that Eureka
should fetch the registry from other Eureka instances, and it should register itself as a
service with the other Eureka servers

if there aren’t other Eureka servers when
in development mode, you’re setting them to false so that Eureka won’t try to reach
out to other Eureka servers.